# Get string from a successful regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to manipulate a string that has tested as a positive match against my regex statement.

My regex statement is `/\[table=\d](.*?)\[\/table] / gmi` and an example of a positive match would be `[table=1]Cell 1[c]Cell 2[/table]`. I'm searching for matches within a certain div, which I'll call `.foo` in the code below.

However, once the search comes back saying it has found a match, I want to have the section that was identified as a match returned back to me so that I can start manipulating a specific section of it, namely count the number of times `[c]` appears and reference the number in `[table=1]`.

```js
(function(regexCheck) {
    var regex = /\[table=\d](.*?)\[\/table] / gmi;
    
 $('.foo').each(function() {
            var html = $(this).html();
            var change = false;

        while (regex[0].test(html)) {
            change = true;
            
     //Somehow return string?
   
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I'm quite new to javascript and especially new to RegEx, so I apologise if this code is crude.

Thanks for all of your help in advance.

Comment: [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Comment: Please make your snippet **runnable** by supplying all the things it relies on (jQuery, elements matching `.foo`), or use simple code blocks instead of a snippet. (But runnable snippets are best.) More about creating runnable snippets: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `exec` instead of `test` and keep the resulting match object:

```
var match;
while ((match = regex[0].exec(html)) != null) {
    change = true;
    // use `match[0]` for the full match, or `match[1]` and onward for capture groups
}
```

Simple example (since your snippet isn't runnable, I've just created a simple one instead):

```js
var str = "test 1 test 2 test 3";
var regex = /test (\d)/g;
var match;
while ((match = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  console.log("match = " + JSON.stringify(match));
}
```